# Python-Tkinter best structuring method

Tags: python, class, tkinter, sh

I have started the construction of a new app, which my intention is to have a center frame that is used to displayed different tables on customer buttoned request.
My initial intention was that each table is constructed by different classes, like:

```
class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master=master)
        self.button_sta = Button(self.button_panel2, text='SandBox Navig', command=lambda: SandBoxNavigator.start())
        self.button_sta.grid(row=3, column=0)


class SandBoxNavigator(MainPage):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(tk.Tk())
        ...  # Manages variables including variables from MainPage

    def run(self):
        ...  # Code to load the table

def main():
    rmtg = tk.Tk()
    MainPage(rmtg)
    rmtg.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But it happens that each time I call SandBoxNavigator it opens a new window as I am asking it to call via super().**init**(tk.Tk()) if I open it via the MainPage. How I can make this class to load the table embedded in a given Frame **or** opens the MainPage if called externally and loads the table (if possible at all), in the most phytonic way?.